# The different faces of max()

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

For

```
l = ["a", "b"]
def bigger(x):
    if x == "a":
        return 1
    return 2
print(max(bigger(letter) for letter in l)) #A
print(max(l, key=bigger))                  #B
print(max(l, key=lambda x: bigger(x)))     #C
```

Output:

```
  2
  b
  b
```

What is A doing that B and C aren't? What is the difference between B and C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference between `B` and `C` apart from a little indirection (the lambda adds an extra layer).

`A` creates numbers, then takes the `max()` of those. `B` and `C` take the `max()` of the list, but `biggest` tells `max()` how to determine relative values for each item in the list.

The `key` function *augments* the items in the list. See it as creating tuples; you take the max from `[(bigger('a'), 'a'), (bigger('b'), 'b')]` then unwrap the tuples again, as if you did `max((bigger(letter), letter) for letter in l)[1]`. For your `A` version, you instead *replace* the elements.